# How do I do this layout in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout

How do I do the following layout:

```
/ header width:100%, height: 100px (this is overlayed)                      /
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/                                         /                                 /
/ div width: all available, height: 100%  /  div width: 200px; height: 100% /
```

Basically, the iFrame width should cover the blue background here: http://jsfiddle.net/VaDTZ/3/

Comment: http://www.utoronto.ca/webdocs/HTMLdocs/NewHTML/

Comment: Any reason for the link...can't see how its relevant?

Comment: picture? a page? a description at least. your giving us code and you are asking for code...

Comment: `position: absolute` can easily do this. Let me know if you'd like a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is something working :)
http://jsfiddle.net/simoncereska/XQJPA/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this easily,

This will ensure that both your primary div, and your sidebar div are the same height.

```
$(document).ready(function({
    var x = $('#primary').height();
    $('#sidebar').css('height', x);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You should design with CSS, not javascript. Would have downvoted, but equal height columns are still a pain after all these years. Still though, jQuery is not the answer to *everything*.

Comment: The height is not the issue...that works. Its the width that's the issue. Would prefer not to use javascript also.

Comment: @Ben: Why don't you take 2 minutes and describe your problems in your post, maybe even make a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: Well I was expecting people to just copy and paste the code, but I can do a jsfiddle demo.